# Gradle won't load usb-serial-for-android libraries

Tags: android, serialization

I have been trying to include [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) libraries in my project but it keeps printing the same error when I try to sync Gradle:

> Error:(26, 0) Project with path ':usb-serial-for-android:usbSerialForAndroid' could not be found in project ':app'.

As you can see, the path [seems correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJYFs.png).

Here is the dependency code:

```
compile project(':usb-serial-for-android:usbSerialForAndroid')
```

Any advice?